# Python Cannot import QtGui

Tags: python

I have Python 3.4 installed, and I am currently using it to create programs for a class project with QtCreator and QtDesigner. Right now I am building a simple test program, but when I go to run it via the command prompt, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: cannot import name QtGui
```

I have PyQt4 installed in the following directory:

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
```

However, I also have a PyQt4 folder in the directory where I am keeping my project files:

```
C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\LMU\Senior Year\Animation Pipeline\PyQt\PyQt4
```

Could the fact that I have two PyQt4 folders be the issue? What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, don't do that! Change your folder name to something else.

Comment: Would i have to change the folder name that contains my project files? If that's the case, wouldn't I just have to get rid of it altogether, or no?

Comment: Just try changing your project folder name(s).

Comment: Okay, so I renamed the project "PyQt4" folder. So, when I import the QtGui, would I import it from that folder or the original PyQt4 folder in the Python34 folder?

Comment: Start a command window from your desktop. Run Python. Type `from PyQt4 import QtGui`. Does that fail? If so, how?

Comment: Alright, in the command prompt, I started up Python and ran that command. It took a few seconds to load, and then another command line came up, so I'm assuming it ran without issue.

Comment: Yep, that means it works :-) In future never run Python from a folder that has the same name as a module you're importing.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try this again here. Hang on one second.